# How to make Spreadsheet automatically add new rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- My spreadsheet just `importrange('SheetName';'A:A')` from another spreadsheet, the number of rows will be more and more and sometimes it will get full causing `#Ref` error, I have to manually go in and add new rows. Is there a way to have the spreadsheet auto add rows on its own every time `Importrange()` needs to add rows? (Because this is an intermediate spreadsheet and the results will go to another spreadsheet). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this function

```
function insertRow() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
};
```

It takes you to the last cell on column A (no matter if it has any data or not, as long as it doesn't have any gaps/empty rows on the way down. If it does, just add extra copies of the `getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)` code line until it gets you there), and then adds a new row after, so you can call it before running your `Importrange()`.

Also, if you want to add more than one row at a time, just change the last argument in

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
```